# Programming Font and Syntax Highlighting Test/Sample Text

Tags: fonts, syntax-highlighting, testing, sample

What is the best text-block to use to test out programming fonts and syntax highlighting?

Comment: That depends on the language...

Comment: I agree that this dependes on the language (I am focused on C/C++), however even between languages there are a lot of similar concerns (' vs ", 0 vs O vs o, 1 vs I vs l, etc) and a good string would probably illustrate common opperators too (like {}, [], ., /, &, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lack of a better answer here is what I have so far:

```
void Il1egal0O(int null){
    switch(1|I[i]){ 
    case check_tab break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The block needs to contain one of each element (one keyword, various symbols, etc) and the String `Il1egal0O`.

It must be simple to distinguish "capital i" from "lower case L" and "O" (letter o) from "0" (number zero).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some code you work with each day - different programs, files etc.